# Установка значения checked radio

Tags: php

Есть две связанные радиокнопки. Хочу, чтобы при определенном выборе на форме, они автоматически меняли статус checked.

```
if ($result[$idc]["delivery"] == 0) {
    //радиокнопка.id1 = checked;

}
```

Как будет корректно выглядеть запись?

Comment: Вы не указали подробностей, что существенно снижает шансы на получение помощи. Вы пишите на чистом PHP? Без использования шаблонизаторов? В целом идея такова используйте переменную, в которой будет храниться либо HTML код, либо true|false и в шаблонизаторе добавляйте вывод его или проверяйте значение.

Comment: Такое лучше на javascript делать, а не на сервере. Мне так кажется.. Может конечно надо именно на сервере, но попахивает извращением...

Answer (score 0):

ну можно просто отрисовывать кнопки через echo, нет?

```
if ($result[$idc]["delivery"] == 0) {
echo ("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"button1\" checked>
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"button2\">");

} else {

echo ("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"button1\">
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"button2\" checked >");
}
```

ну и красоту допилить) хотя согласен с предыдущим оратором по поводу бдсм)

Comment: `<input type="radio"<?=(!$result[$idc]["delivery"])?" checked":""?>>` :)